# "Logically slower" algorithm turns out to be faster, but why?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, tree, visibility

I've implemented two different algorithms which do essentially the same, check for visibility from one node to another in a tree of nodes, with the rules being simple - a node is only visible to another node if it precedes it along the same branch.

The first method goes down the tree from child to parent, skipping other potential children in the parent to get the tree indices for both nodes and uses some basic logic to determine if there is visibility. I decided to go for this one first because I already had the methods for the node indices which I needed for something else and I assumed it to be potentially faster.

```
bool isVisibleTo(Node * accessor) {
  QList<uint> accessedI = getIndex();
  QList<uint> accessorI = accessor->getIndex();
  if (accessedI.size() > accessorI.size()) {
    return false; 
  } else if (accessedI.size() == accessorI.size()) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < accessedI.size() - 1; ++i) {
      if (accessedI.at(i) != accessorI.at(i)) {
        return false; 
      }
    }
    if (accessedI.last() > accessorI.last()) {
      return false; 
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < accessorI.size() - (accessorI.size() - accessedI.size()); ++i) {
    if (accessedI.at(i) > accessorI.at(i)) {
      return false; 
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

The second one traverses the tree completely, every child down to the parent and so on, going through significantly more nodes and I can only assume memory pages and cache lines.

```
bool isVisibleTo2(Node * accessor) {
  Node * node = accessor;
  while (node) {
    if (node == this)
      return true;
    if (node->_parent) {
      uint i = node->_parent->_children.indexOf(node);
      while (i) {
        if (node->_parent->_children.at(--i) == this) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    node = node->_parent;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I expected this to be the slower algorithm for big trees. But it turned out to be 10-20 times faster for small trees and as the tree size increased it stuck at a consistent 4x better in the last few test, the final of which took about 20 minutes and involved 10 million nodes in the tree (granted most of the time was the node allocation, the actual visibility check was several seconds).

So what are those performance figures due to? Considering that they provide identical results (checked that thoroughly - there is no work saved by the second method) and the first method involves fewer memory hops and I assume is much more cache friendly and also it can just check the depth and do a much shorter evaluation? Granted it does 2 traversals rather than one, but they are directly child to parent, skipping the rest of the children along the way. And yes, I do realize the second method does not need to go all the way down, but still...

Edit: I switched to `-O3` compilation, but the figures did not change. I also tried to change the list of `getIndex` to a vector but it actually caused a substantial performance drop, since the indices need to be inserted in reverse order, e.g. prepended, which is very inefficient for a vector.

Edit 2: Did a quick test with a vector once again, this time I scrapped prepending and went of a regular insert and a reverse operation before returning, this made the vector solution slightly faster, from 8 times slower than the full traversal method to "only" 6 times slower. I suspected that the `QList` allocations might be the primary culprit for the low performance, but as it seems, there is something more to it.

Comment: Have you done a iteration count, or do you know the figures?

Comment: @Stefan - no I have not, it would be pointless at this point, when it is just a random abstract tree and does not reflect its actual future intended use. I will likely keep both methods to check it later on, but I am still curious about the performance at this point.

Comment: What platform are you on?  What compiler and options are you using?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - GCC 4.7 x32 on windows 7 64, i7 @ 3.4 Ghz 16GB DDR3-1600

Comment: I am not sure, it is "default settings" for Qt Creator, I assume no optimization flags.

Comment: You have a curious code formatting style...

Comment: I can't be sure without all the code, but you might want to profile the `getIndex()` functions. They may copy a lot of elements/pointers, and allocate memory for them. On the other hand, the second algorithm only accesses them, without copy.

Comment: @ddriver *Never* reason about performance on non-optimised code. That's like judging who's the fastest runner based on how well the contestants can read maps...

Comment: @biskitt - Qt containers use implicit sharing, so they are not copied, I might switch to a vector though, but I doubt it will have a big impact.

Comment: I agree with @biskitt:  The `QList<uint>` declarations and `getIndex()` may be doing quite a lot of work behind your back.

Comment: @Angew - that's the reason I tried both, i am just surprised by the results.

Comment: @ddriver I meant non-optimised in the sense of "compiled without optimisation flags."

Comment: BTW, what is the actual definition of `Node`, and just what exactly does `_children.indexOf()` and `_children.at(i)` do?  Do those recurse back down into the tree?

Comment: @JoeZ - no, it just looks up the index of the object in a `QList`, the `at` method is identical to the `[]` operator.

Comment: @ddriver:  Your second version seems to do minimal work then.  It's not recursive at all, and has very simple loops that should schedule nicely.  If `indexOf` implies a loop, then you could make the second one _even faster_ by instead doing something like this:  `for (i = 0; node->_parent->_children.at(i) != node; i++) if (node->_parent->_children.at(i) == this) return true;`  (You might rewrite that to reuse the result of `.at(i)`, but you get the idea.)

Comment: What does getIndex do?

Comment: @klm123 - it returns a list of the indices of the node in the tree down to the root.

Comment: @ddriver I edited your code in a way that should not change how it works at all (just adding `{}` and newlines) so it is slightly more conventionally formatted.  Can you double check I didn't do something horrible and make it behave differently?

Comment: @ddriver That is what `getIndex` returns.  What does it *do*?  If `getIndex` spends 5 hours playing MP3 files, then returns that list, it will perform differently, but return the exact same thing.  What does `getIndex` *do*?  Does it by any chance `uint i = node->_parent->_children.indexOf(node)` or something equivalent?  (source would be good)

Comment: Depending a lot on your tree repartition, if you have many sibling and not too deep tree you could store a vector of all parents till root for node and this then compare first and last of the shortest to same position of the other. it may reduce the work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the `getIndex()` function, which you call in the first case does basically the same walk over all tree, which `isVisibleTo2()` does. But `isVisibleTo1()` has additional to getIndex operations, therefore it is slower.

Comment: No, `getIndes` takes a huge shortcut - it only goes from child to parent down to the root, while the second method goes through every child along the way.

Comment: @ddriver, from which child to which parent? Could you just give a code of this and indexOf() functions?

Comment: From the parameter `Node` to its parent down to its parent and so forth down to the root. `getIndex` skips all other siblings/children of its parent.

Comment: @ddriver, I don't see any parameters at getIndex() function.

Comment: The parameter of `isVisibleTo`. The difference is that getIndex goes fro Node -> parent -> parent -> parent until the root, while in `isVisible2` it goes child -> child -> child -> until the parent, then switches the parent to a "child" context, down all the children to the next parent, all children to the next parent until the root.

Comment: @ddriver, sorry, I can't get it without functions definitions. If you don't want to present them here I hope someone else will help you.

Comment: This is the code `QList<uint> list; Node * node = this; while (node->_parent) { list.prepend(node->_parent->_children.indexOf(node)); node = node->_parent; } list.prepend(0); return list;`

Comment: So the `getIndex` function  creates a list with at a maximum of `tree depth` elements. It does memory alocations, which should be slower than direct access to tree elements. And much more slower it the tree is huge. Did you checked the memory consumption ot both functions during execution?

Comment: I don't have profiling software, and memory consumption from the list is very tiny relative to all the Nodes to measure it in the task manager, plus it goes away very quickly.

Comment: That appears to be the culprit, even though the tree as it is randomly generated right now doesn't get too deep even for millions of nodes.

Comment: No, it wasn't the list, I eliminated the vast majority of allocations and performance is still much worse for the first method. I guess it is something else.

Comment: @ddriver, could you update you post with most recent version of you coude?

Answer (score 0):

More info on the actual structure methods might change this but:

the other possible difference here is branch predictability

It seems like the second version might be more predictable than the first

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. The problem with the first version is that you are calling getIndex() twice, which *allocates memory*. You can prove it or disprove it by posting your code for getIndex().

There is nothing 'logically slower' about not calling into an expensive function, by the way.